# How should I do if my ubuntu are freezing?

Tags: wireless-networking, freeze, multi-boot

I have a lot of PC which have dual boot system(install ubuntu 10.10 in windows xp).
All PC are connected to ubuntu server use wireless router.

All PC is use for input data to server use Php and also Mysql. But almost of PC become freeze up if idle for long time(5 minutes not use). My hard disk still have a lot of empty space.

how should i do to fix this?
what is the step should i do to check this problem?

Comment: You could do one of two things in preparation. Either: a) 'tail the syslog' by opening a terminal and doing `$ tail -f /var/log/syslog` or b) go System > Administration > Log File Viewer and have it readily available for when a freeze occurs. That way we can get a bit more info as to what's happening when a crash occurs.

Comment: I have tried that and show: `CRON[1699]: (root) CMD (cd/&& run-parts--report /etc/cron.hourly)` and `Kernel:kernel logging (proc) stopped`